# copy of Ubuntu linux

Tags: windows-xp

I am hoping you can help me. I Have a windows xp machine and instead of throwing it out, I would like to install Ubuntu Linux on to it.

However, I am having trouble trying to copy the os on to a disc and I was wondering if you knew where I can get a copy from?

I appreciate any assistance you can give on this.

Comment: Can you post your hardware specifications (CPU, RAM etc), perhaps Lubuntu or Xubuntu could be the better choice http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a DVD with the latest version (14.04 LTS) here:
http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=1146

but its a 64-bit version, so check your computer first.
I think that you can't buy a 32-bit version, you have to download it or make your own CD.

But you can get help for making your own CD if you are stuck.
Start here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

Answer (score 0):

[Here.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Perhaps you need to change some stuff in your computer's BIOS before you can install from a CD or a USB stick, for example the boot sequence (which may mor may not be 1. hard disk, 2. CD/DVD drive, 3. USB devices, 4. network).

This - [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) - will also be helpful, especially if you want to install Ubuntu from a USB drive, or if you want to experiment with different kinds of Linux before installing anything.

Comment: If you want to install from USB use this http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows Unebootin can make [problems](http://blog.husainad.com/installing-ubuntu-13-04-mouse-touchpad-not-working/).